# what predictive analysis will work with this data set?

Tags: predictive-modeling, random-forest

I have a dataset that includes all of the building permits that were issued for homes within a city. I have the data in a "snapshot" from a year ago (and potentially a few others, older snapshots) and today.

Included in the data are things like home age and other attributes about the home. What I'm hoping to do is figure out what characteristics predict a future permit. For this, I was going to compare the year ago snapshot with the present snapshot to see which homes ended up getting permits (e.g., to remodel a bathroom) and determine if there's any correlation between characteristics that predict these.

My questions are the following:

- **What form would I need the data to do this?** Assume I have all the characteristics in different "columns". Most of it will be categorical or binary (true/false). Dates will obviously be in date format. I have the ability to add additional flags in the past or current data that might indicate, for example, a new plumbing permit was issued.
- **What analysis would work best for this and any recommendations for tools/platforms to run this?** Assuming hundreds of thousands of entries would be available to analyze.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have examples of permits that were not granted?

Comment: @JanvanderVegt Good question. I'm almost positive that we don't have that data.

Comment: Your question appears very generic. Try to be more specific. Or add a head(data.frame) to see your actual data and enable people to provide more detailed suggestions.

Comment: Multivariate analysis or logistic regression could be implemented if you are able to find enough numerical data from permits . This problem is similar to predicting bad loans . example - http://www.tgslc.org/pdf/tamu_multivariate_analysis.pdf

Comment: You need to be more  precise about what you are predicting here.  You are not predicting a "future permit."  You are predicting whether there will be a permit given in the next year.